# Is there a per-user swapfile?

Tags: encryption, swap

The goal is to encrypt a swap area, making it unreadable by other users. Maybe even attempting to `dm-crypt` a separate user's `/home` partition.

May it seem any way possible?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Sorry for the short answer!

Comment: Again no, sorry.